# Delphi get IP from network name

Tags: delphi, networking, delphi-xe5

Ok guys, I've dug and dug, including on this site, and can't find any solution to this.

Assume several computers are connected to a network and all are in the same workgroup.  I can easily get a list of all their network names, like //MYCOMPUTER-PC.  I'm trying to get all of the local IP address of these machines (not just the current machine) i.e. 192.168.0.1 without having to physically connect to every possible IP and test a connection.

So far everything I've tried has failed.  Either I can only get the IP address of the machine I'm running on or, I get the ip address for Searchguide (198.105.244.65) which is where my ISP defaults when an IP address can't be found.

Here's the code I'm using that fails.  If I leave the \ in the network name, I get an unknown result. If I remove the \ I get the Searchguide IP:

```
function GetIPAddress(NetworkName: String): String;
var
Error: DWORD;
HostEntry: PHostEnt;
Data: WSAData;
Address: In_Addr;
begin
     Error:=WSAStartup(MakeWord(1, 1), Data);
     if Error = 0 then 
     begin
          HostEntry:=gethostbyname(PansiChar(NetworkName));
          Error:=GetLastError();
          if Error = 0 then 
          begin
               Address:=PInAddr(HostEntry^.h_addr_list^)^;
               Result:=inet_ntoa(Address);
          end
          else 
          begin
               Result:='Unknown';
          end;
     end
     else
     begin
          Result:='Error';
     end;
     WSACleanup();
end;
```

So, assuming I know nothing about the router these computers are connected to, is it even possible to get a list of local IP's???

Thanks

*edit*

Here's an image of it's output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using XE5, string is unicode, you are not passing host name to `gethostbyname` but some garbage. Replace

```
HostEntry:=gethostbyname(PansiChar(NetworkName));
```

with

```
HostEntry:=gethostbyname(PansiChar(AnsiString(NetworkName)));
```

Additionally test the return of `gethostbyname` for success, not the last error. Use documentation of the api for proper usage. Also use `WSAGetLastError` to retrieve winsock error code (as documented), not `GetLastError`.

Comment: Ok, tried it. That went from getting all of the computers on the network to being 198.105.244.65 to all but the one I'm on, which it listed the correct IP for.  All the others are still the IP for Searchguide

Comment: You are passing DNS names, aren't you? Not //MYCOMPUTER-PC or \\MYCOMPUTER-PC but MYCOMPUTER-PC

Comment: Just added a screenshot to show you what it's doing.

Comment: You're sure the addresses are resolvable, tested with  nslookup?

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with nslookup. All I have is the demo that comes with ICS and I'm not sure what I'm looking at with it's results.  But, doesn't NS lookup only deal with internet IP's?

Comment: The address class doesn't matter. But I think actually it may not help if you need netbios name resolution.

Comment: You write "tried it both ways". You need to try it without // or \\ as nither is needed.

Comment: And you sould compare your result to what you get by doing a "ping MYCOMPUTER-PC" from a command prompt.

Comment: And you should stop using the legacy `gethostbyname()` function and use the newer `getaddrinfo()` function instead.